# Simple TensorFlow (Keras) model using tf.tensor objects of structured data

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have two tensor objects, `train` and `labels`. The dataset `train` has 100 features, and `labels` has 1 feature. Both `train` and `labels` have M entries. Similarly, we have a `dev` and `dev_labels` set with the same respective number of features and N entries. After importing Keras from TensorFlow, we creating a neural network as follows:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=[100]),
    keras.layers.Dense(100, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Now we want to fit the model, with batches of size P for Q epochs.

```
model.fit(train_X, train_Y, validation_data=(dev_X, dev_Y), epochs=Q, steps_per_epoch=??, validation_steps=??)
```

After reading the documentation on model.fit, I am still not sure what would be the correct `steps_per_epoch` or `validation_steps` here. When using data tensors as input to a model, these parameters must be specified. In this example, what would we specify for `steps_per_epoch` and `validation_steps`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

steps_per_epoch should be roughly equal to number of training examples divided by batch size (default is 32). Similarly validation_steps should be roughly equal to number of validation examples divided by batch size. You can find the documentation [here](https://keras.io/models/model/).

> steps_per_epoch: Integer or None. Total number of steps (batches of
> samples) before declaring one epoch finished and starting the next
> epoch. When training with input tensors such as TensorFlow data
> tensors, the default None is equal to the number of samples in your
> dataset divided by the batch size, or 1 if that cannot be determined.
>
> validation_steps: Only relevant if steps_per_epoch is specified. Total
> number of steps (batches of samples) to validate before stopping.

In your case they should be

```
steps_per_epoch = len(train_X) / batch_size
validation_steps = len(dev_X) / batch_size
```

Comment: This is pretty close, except len cannot be applied to a tf.tensor object. I think you meant something like the following:
`steps_per_epoch = int(int(train_X.shape[0]) / batch_size)`
`validation_steps = int(int(dev_X.shape[0]) / batch_size)`

Comment: Yes I didn't mean to write a working code. Besides you also need to decide what to do when length is not a multiple of batch size.